# Seperation of variables is not rigorous enough.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have started ODE's and have been told that solving initial value problems by using separation of variables(like I had been taught) is nothing but a leap of faith. Now we must use something along the lines, If $u$ is a solution of the IVP then $u = G^{-1} \circ F$ etc. I can accept this, and understand the proof of, but what about a question like:

Determine all positive solutions to the equation

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{u}, x >0$$

This is not an initial value problem, so how do I tackle this with rigor?

Comment: $u'(x) = 1/u(x)$ so $u'(x)u(x) = 1$ so $\int_a^x u'(y) u(y) dy = \int_a^x 1 dy$ so ...

Comment: You would be interested in http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7984/1550, which sketches how to deal with non-unique solutions rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{d}{dx}u^2=2u\frac{du}{dx}=2$$
and so $u(x)^2=2x+c$, etc (you must choose the intervals of definition so that $u$ doesn't vanish, because of the initial equation).

Incidentally, the method of separation of variables is not a "leap of faith". Simply, it can be applied to almost no equation.

Comment: I see, I am now only coming to terms with the fact that I can not use that old chestnut anymore. What is the $U$ in your answer? The anti-derivative? just so I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppose that $u\ne0$. Then you have
$$1=uu' = (\frac{1}{2}u^2)'$$
Integrate to get
$$\frac{1}{2}u^2 = x + c$$